# Новогодний алгоритм 2016

Tags: поддержка, соревнование

Спешим предложить вам принять участие в новогоднем конкурсе на лучшие вопросы и ответы по метке [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc).

Правила просты – необходимо задавать вопросы и отвечать на них :)

*Формальные условия*. В игре участвуют все вопросы заданные с 1–го по 31-е января 2016 года с меткой [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc), а также ответы данные за аналогичный период на вопросы по метке [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)<sup>*</sup>. По задумке, вопросы участвующие в конкурсе должны относится к разряду академических.

*<sub>Учитывается время создания конкретного сообщения, таким образом, если будет опубликован ответ, соответствующий критериям, на ранее заданный вопрос, он также будет учитываться при подсчете результатов.</sub>

*Победители*. Победителем будет считаться:

1. Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом.
2. Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.
3. Автор ответа на свой вопрос, если ответ получит больший рейтинг, чем любой другой ответ к этому же вопросу.
4. Автор принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.
5. Автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов.
6. Автор вопроса с наибольшим количеством просмотров.
7. Автор наибольшего количества вопросов.
8. Автор наибольшего количества ответов.

Среди всех сообщений удовлетворяющих условию выбирается одно, с наибольшим рейтингом или опубликованное ранее. «Зимние игры» пройдут в две сессии.

- *Первая сессия*: с первого января по десятое января.
- *Вторая сессия*: с одиннадцатого января по тридцать первое января.

В каждой сессии будут свои победители. Приз вручается однажды, таким образом если вы станете лучшим в одной категории несколько раз или лучшим в нескольких категориях в одной сессии приз будет все равно один, но за каждую победу в категории дается один призовой балл. Лидеру «зимних игр», то есть участнику набравшему наибольшее количество призовых баллов, будет вручен секретный супер–приз.

*Приз*: оранжевая футболка Stack Overflow на русском, блокнот, наклейки, флеш–накопители и другие памятные призы! Истинным призом, конечно же, будут знания, и только ради них уже стоит принять участие.

Знаете того, кто может задать отличный вопрос по алгоритмам? Милости просим в сообщество!

С нетерпением ждем ваших вопросов с меткой [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) (не забудьте подписаться на нее, чтобы не пропустить новые вопросы)!

**Обновление**

Подсчет результатов будет осуществляться по прошествию 10 дней с момента окончания срока, чтобы уровнять шансы получения голосов.

**Обновление 2**

Пример запросов для выявления победителей.

1. Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.Score 
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2016-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2016-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
2. Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2016-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2016-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
3. Автор ответа на свой вопрос, если ответ получит больший рейтинг, чем любой другой ответ к этому же вопросу. (Находит ответы на свои вопросы)

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.OwnerUserId = parent.OwnerUserId AND p.CreationDate >= '2016-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2016-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
4. Автор принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.Id = parent.AcceptedAnswerId AND p.CreationDate >= '2016-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2016-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
5. Автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.AnswerCount, p.Score  
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2016-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2016-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.AnswerCount desc, p.Score desc;
   ```
6. Автор вопроса с наибольшим количеством просмотров.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, m.ViewCount, p.Score 
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
     Join PostMetadata m on m.PostId = p.Id
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2016-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2016-01-11' 
   ORDER BY m.ViewCount desc, p.Score desc;
   ```
7. Автор наибольшего количества вопросов.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, COUNT (DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2016-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2016-01-11' 
   GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
   ORDER BY Number desc;
   ```
8. Автор наибольшего количества ответов.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, COUNT(DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2016-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2016-01-11' 
   GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
   ORDER BY Number desc;
   ```

### Победителями первой сессии стали

- Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом, автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов и автор вопроса с наибольшим количеством просмотров. Победителем становится [@Simankov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15637/) за вопрос «[Как убрать ошибки измерений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479508/)», набравший 14 голосов за, получивший 5 ответов и 231 просмотр.
- Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом и автор ответа на свой вопрос, если ответ получит больший рейтинг, чем любой другой ответ к этому же вопросу. Победителем становится [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/) за ответ на вопрос «[Различаются ли строки не более чем на один символ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479325/6)», который набрал 9 голосов за!
- Автор принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом. Победителем становится [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/) за ответ на вопрос «[Различаются ли строки не более чем на один символ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479372/6)», который набрал 8 голосов за!
- Автор наибольшего количества вопросов. За сессию все разместили ровно по одному вопросу. Победителем становится [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/), так как он сделал это раньше всех!
- Автор наибольшего количества ответов. Победителем становится [@Yuri Negometyanov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194380/), за публикацию 9 ответов на вопросы с меткой [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc).

Поздравляю победителей! По завершении конкурса, я свяжусь с вами для уточнения деталей для отправки призов. После первой сессии появились два претендента на супер приз! Ими стали: [@Simankov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15637/) и [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/). У каждого по три победы в разных номинациях. Так держать!

С нетерпением ждем результатов второй сессии «Новогоднего алгоритма 2016»!

**Обновление 3**

### Победителями второй сессии стали

- Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом. Победителем становится [@metalurgus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3997/) за вопрос «[Алгоритм определения радиуса окружности, в которую можно вписать текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486523/)», набравший 8 голосов за.
- Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом. Победителем становится [@Abyx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/) за ответ на вопрос «[Однонаправленый линейный список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482887/6)», который набрал 9 голосов за!
- Автор ответа на свой вопрос, если ответ получит больший рейтинг, чем любой другой ответ к этому же вопросу. Победителем становится [@ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/) за ответ на свой вопрос «[Как узнать количество строк кода в проекте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486415/6)», который набрал 6 голосов за!
- Автор принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом. Победителем становится [@Андрей Курулёв](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184419/) за ответ на вопрос «[Проблема при слияние строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484911/6)», который набрал 10 голосов за!
- Автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов. Победителем становится [@yevgeniyche](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23515/yevgeniyche) за вопрос «[Поиск всех слов в любом порядке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486345/)», на который было опубликовано 5 ответов!
- Автор вопроса с наибольшим количеством просмотров. Победителем становится [@Denis Khvorostin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7295/) за вопрос «[Алгоритм определения возможных замен ключевых компонентов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/483160/6)», получивший 272 просмотра.
- Автор наибольшего количества вопросов. Победителем становится [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/), задав четыре вопроса.
- Автор наибольшего количества ответов. Победителем становится [@Yuri Negometyanov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194380/), опубликовав 11 ответов на вопросы с меткой [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc).

Поздравляю победителей! В ближайшее время я свяжусь с вами для уточнения деталей отправки призов!

**Победителем по сумме побед становится [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/), за четыре победы в разных номинациях!** Мы рады объявить супер приз: билет на одну любую конференцию по программированию в России в текущем году!

Огромное спасибо всем, кто принял участие в конкурсе!

Comment: получается олимпийские задачи тоже будем задавать?

Comment: @Saidolim Конечно!

Comment: возможно стоит также рассмотреть ответы на *старые* вопросы, которые можно отнести к метке [tag:алгоритм], и учитывать голоса за/просмотры вопроса, набранные после его правки.

Comment: @jfs Отличное предложение! Дополнил правила.

Comment: А актуальный рейтинг где-то можно смотреть? На DataSE, например? Кстати, если там сделать, то насколько он будет актуальным, т. е. как часто там данные обновляются?

Comment: @Qwertiy DataSE обновляется раз в неделю, на сколько я помню. Также есть аналогичный внутренний сервис, позволяющий делать запросы в реальном времени. Я через него планирую отслеживать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а как-то расшарить статистику?

Comment: @Qwertiy Если вы имеете в виду, опубликовать результаты, то конечно же я опубликую статистику. Если вы о чем-то другом, пожалуйста, уточните, про что именно.

Comment: Я о том, что хотелось бы где-то видеть более-менее актуальную статистику с лидерами по категориям. Ну хотя бы с обновлением раз в день, а лучше почаще.

Comment: Хотел бы уточнить: если вопрос задан 5 января, а ответ дан 15 января, то в какой из сессий участвует ответ? Будет ли вопрос участвовать в обеих сессиях?

Comment: @Qwertiy: добавил ссылки на текущий топ вопросов, по ним можно получить хотя бы общее представление.

Comment: Чтобы уравнять шансы вопросов, заданных 1 и 10 января, предлагаю считать результаты по ним с задержкой хотя бы в неделю, т.е. 17 января. Аналогично для второй сессии.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Хорошее предложение. Если никто не выскажется против, можно будет внести в формулировку условий.

Comment: Завтра подсчёт результатов первого тура.

Comment: Добавил пример выборки, по которой буду завтра искать победителей. Если что-то не верно, пожалуйста, поправьте.

Comment: Запросы - это хорошо, но они ведь непроверяемы...

Comment: @Qwertiy Почему же? Раз в неделю обновляется [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). Вы лично можете выполнить все запросы и посмотреть результаты.

Comment: Я уже на js написал часть - скоро выложу :) А раз в неделю - это редко.

Comment: в 6. указан PostMetadata -- Invalid object name 'PostMetadata' при запросе через https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/new

Comment: Интересно, возможно схема базы для внутреннего использования отличается.

Comment: Официальные результаты не пора объявлять?

Comment: Горячий привет из Киева! На правах призёра по номинации № 8 хочу выразить благодарность всей дружной команде СО за качественное наполнение и модерирование сайта, а организаторам также за ощутимое неравнодушие к СО и за качественное проведение конкурса. Имея за плечами нереальный стаж математика, программиста, алгоритмиста и АСУТП-шника и оказавшись на пенсии после сложной борьбы за жизнь, я нашёл здесь свою нишу. И особая благодарность - за памятные призы, которые уже получил.

Answer (score 5):

Скрипт для определения текущих результатов по:

1. Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом.
2. Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.
3. Автор ответа на свой вопрос, если ответ получит больший рейтинг, чем любой другой ответ к этому же вопросу.
4. Автор принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.
5. Автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов.
6. Автор вопроса с наибольшим количеством просмотров.
7. Автор наибольшего количества вопросов.
8. Автор наибольшего количества ответов.

```
var limits = "2016-01-11..2016-01-31";

$.get("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5B%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%5D+created%3A" + limits + "+is%3Aq").then(data => {
  var qs = [], as = [];

  $((new DOMParser).parseFromString(data, 'text/html')).find(".question-summary").each((i, el) => {
    var $q = $(el);

    qs.push({
      user: $q.find(".started.fr a").text(),
      id: +$q.find(".result-link a").attr("href").match(/questions\/(\d+)\//)[1],
      title: $q.find(".result-link a").prop('title'),
      votes: +$q.find(".vote-count-post strong").text(),
      answers: +$q.find(".status strong").text(),
      accepted: !!$q.find(".answered-accepted").length
    });
  });

  $.when($.get("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5B%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%5D+created%3A" + limits + "+is%3Aa").then(data => {
    $((new DOMParser).parseFromString(data, 'text/html')).find(".question-summary").each((i, el) => {
      var $a = $(el);

      as.push({
        user: $a.find(".started.fr a").text(),
        qid: +$a.find(".result-link a").attr("href").match(/questions\/(\d+)\//)[1],
        id: +$a.find(".result-link a").attr("href").match(/#(\d+)$/)[1],
        title: $a.find(".result-link a").prop('title'),
        votes: +$a.find(".vote-count-post strong").text(),
        accepted: !!$a.find(".votes.answered").length
      });
    });
  }), ...qs.map(q => $.get("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/" + q.id + "?answertab=votes").then(data => {
    var $doc = $((new DOMParser).parseFromString(data, 'text/html'));
    q.views = parseInt($doc.find("#qinfo tr:nth-child(2) b").text());

    var ans = $doc.find(".answer").map((i,a) => {
      var $a = $(a);
      return {
        votes: +$a.find(".vote-count-post").text(),
        isOwn: !!$a.find(".post-signature.owner").length
      };
    }).sort((a,b) => b.votes-a.votes);

    q.bestOwnAnswer = ans.length
      ? ans[0].isOwn
        ? ans.length === 1
          ? "Single: " + ans[0].votes
          : ans[0].votes === ans[1].votes ? "Equal: " + ans[0].votes : `Best: ${ans[0].votes} (next: ${ans[1].votes})`
        : ""
      : "";
  }))).done(() => {
    qs.sort((a,b) => b.votes-a.votes);
    console.log();
    console.table(qs);
    console.log("1. Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом.");

    as.sort((a,b) => b.votes-a.votes);
    console.log();
    console.table(as);
    console.log("2. Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.");

    qs.sort((a,b) => b.bestOwnAnswer.match(/\d+/)-a.bestOwnAnswer.match(/\d+/));
    console.log();
    console.table(qs.filter(q => q.bestOwnAnswer));
    console.log("3. Автор ответа на свой вопрос, если ответ получит больший рейтинг, чем любой другой ответ к этому же вопросу.");

    as.sort((a,b) => b.votes-a.votes);
    console.log();
    console.table(as.filter(a => a.accepted));
    console.log("4. Автор принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.");

    qs.sort((a,b) => b.answers-a.answers)
    console.log();
    console.table(qs);
    console.log("5. Автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов.");

    qs.sort((a,b) => b.views-a.views)
    console.log();
    console.table(qs);
    console.log("6. Автор вопроса с наибольшим количеством просмотров.");

    var uqa = {};
    for (var q of qs) { uqa[q.user] = uqa[q.user] || {}; uqa[q.user].q = ~~uqa[q.user].q + 1; }
    for (var a of as) { uqa[a.user] = uqa[a.user] || {}; uqa[a.user].a = ~~uqa[a.user].a + 1; }
    uqa = Object.keys(uqa).map(u => ({ user:u, questions:~~uqa[u].q, answers:~~uqa[u].a }));

    uqa.sort((a,b) => b.questions-a.questions);
    console.log();
    console.table(uqa/*.filter(u => u.questions)*/);
    console.log("7. Автор наибольшего количества вопросов.");

    uqa.sort((a,b) => b.answers-a.answers);
    console.log();
    console.table(uqa/*.filter(u => u.answers)*/);
    console.log("8. Автор наибольшего количества ответов.");
  });  
})
```

Скрипт надо выполнять в консоли Хрома (в FF и Edge не проверялся; в IE и Опере 12 работать не будет) на любой странице ruSO (но не metaRuSO). Результаты будут выведены в консоль в виде таблиц. Название таблицы пишется под таблицей.

Если поменять значение `limits`, то можно посмотреть для другого периода.

## Примерный результат по первой части конкурса:

[image: Результат по первой части 20.01.2016 примерно в 01:50 UTC]

## Примерный результат по второй части конкурса:

[image: Результат по второй части 10.02.2016 примерно в 07:30 UTC]

Answer (score 3):

### Ссылки на актуальную статистику.

#### Первая сессия: с первого января по десятое января.

- [Лучшие вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC]%20created%3a2016-01-01..2016-01-10%20is%3aq)
- [Лучшие ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC]%20created%3a2016-01-01..2016-01-10%20is%3aa)

#### Вторая сессия: с одиннадцатого января по тридцать первое января.

- [Лучшие вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC]%20created%3a2016-01-11..2016-01-31%20is%3aq)
- [Лучшие ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC]%20created%3a2016-01-11..2016-01-31%20is%3aa)

Comment: Спасибо. Но номинаций 8, а не 2 :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: ну это хотя бы что-то. В SEDE не могу )

Comment: Ну я плюсик уже поставил :) Кстати, не знал, что так с датами можно.

Comment: @Qwertiy [В справке есть](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) описание разнообразных примирений фильтров.