# В каком случае загружаемое изображение конвертируется?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, imgur

Собственно, почему некоторые картинки при загрузке преобразуются из png в jpg (причём другого размера) и как можно этого избежать, чтобы не происходило значительного ухудшения качества?

Пример: в этом [ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2372/178988)
[эта картика осталась в png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjpcP.png)
[а эта стала jpg с заметными артефактами :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Jxg.jpg)
При загрузке обе были в png менее 1МБ (первая 400К, вторая 1М).

Оказывается, там ещё и размер поменялся. Был 1875*5706, а стал 1444*4394.

Comment: Вот это интересное поведение. Не замечал такого.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть похожий вопрос на MSE и [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350230/339911) к нему. Приведу здесь кратко выдержки по-русски.

> Максимальный размер файлов на imgur для неанимированных изображений (JPG, PNG и
> т.п.) составляет 20Мб. PNG файлы более 5Мб конвертируются в JPEG.
>
> [...]
>
> Неанимированне изображения более 1Мб для анонимных загрузок и более
> 5Мб для владельцев учётных записей подвергаются сжатию с потерями.

Пользователи сайтов Stack Exchange при загрузке изображений рассматриваются как анонимные, и стало быть ограничение соотвествует 1Мб.

Хорошо бы узнать точный размер второго файла, который претерпел конвертирование, т.к. если его размер действительно меньше 1Мб, то сжатия быть не должно. Хотя может быть 4 года назад ограничения были несколько иные.

Comment: Не уверен, что смогу найти тот файл. Ещё может быть фишка с 1000 и 1024 - что размер между ними, поэтому у меня меньше, а для них больше.

Comment: @Qwertiy типа "в программистском килограмме 1024 грамма"?

Comment: Я мог иметь в виду, что файл меньше 1048576 байт. Но при этом он мог быть больше 1e6.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, я как раз об этом. Производители дисков тоже такое любят.