# Какие конференции вы посещаете или хотели бы посетить?

Tags: обсуждение

Миссия Stack Overflow (вне зависимости от предпочитаемого сообществом языка) – сделать Интернет лучшим местом для того, чтобы получить качественный ответ по программированию. Шаг за шагом мы вместе воплощаем эту идею в реальность! Хотя сегодня любой профессиональный разработчики или энтузиаст программирования может получить ответ даже на крайне сложный вопрос на сайте, нам, людям, [свойственно общение в реальной жизни](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0). Как мне кажется, было бы крайне интересно узнать, где можно встретить участников сообщества Stack Overflow, а также услышать их рекомендацию к посещению таких мероприятий.

Пожалуйста, расскажите, какие конференции (встречи, мастер классы и т. д.) по программированию вы посещаете? Какие хотели бы посетить?

На основе отзывов сообщества мы сможем сформировать список лучших конференций (мастер классов, встреч), на которые в будущем мы сможем [отправлять](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2235/) авторов лучших вопросов и ответов (при наличии у них такого желания).

Comment: а как отвечать то? отдельным ответом писать конференцию, и по количеству апвоутов определять сколько людей туда ездит?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Да, скорее всего, это один из самых удачных вариантов.

Answer (score 5):

Профессиональная конференция разработчиков высоконагруженных систем

http://www.highload.ru/

Даже не знаю, что и добавить. Хайлоад он и есть хайлоад.

Answer (score 5):

Конференции и мероприятия от Яндекса весьма любопытны.

https://events.yandex.ru/

Регулярно проводятся во многих городах. Тематик множество (Разработка/Маркетинг/Наука/Документирование/...)

Очень хорошо организованы онлайн-трансляции. Также, в любое время, на сайте можно глянуть доклады с прошедших мероприятий.

Answer (score 4):

Ну кому Джава, тому в России на конференции JUG.ru Group - [Joker](http://jokerconf.com), [JPoint](http://javapoint.ru), [JBreak](http://jbreak.ru), в Украине на [JavaDays](http://javaday.org.ua), а в Беларуси на [JET](http://jetconf.by#/).

Comment: Что-то более локальное: JavaDayKazan

Answer (score 2):

Относительно недавно была конференция [DUMP](http://dump-conf.ru/) в Екатеринбурге. Интересные доклады, вкусная еда, скидки на билеты студентам.

Видео докладов на хабре: [DUMP-2016: видео всех докладов в одном посте. Бесплатно. Без СМС](https://habrahabr.ru/company/it_people/blog/302286/).

Answer (score 2):

[PG Day](http://pgday.ru) в Санкт-Петербурге для postgre-водов: как админов так и разработчиков. Юзкейсы, кластера, производительность, доклады от создателей о кишочках.

Answer (score 1):

CodeFest

http://2016.codefest.ru/

Конференция по разработке, тестированию, администрированию, дизайну и IT-менеджменту в Новосибирске.

Answer (score 1):

.NET'чикам сюда: http://dotnext.ru

Единственная действительно общероссийская конференция по .NET. Минимум маркетинга, максимум технического хардкора. Присутствуют иностранные докладчики.

Comment: Было бы здорово увидеть вашу рецензию на конференцию!

Answer (score 0):

NeoQUEST

http://neoquest.ru

**Место:** Санкт-Петербург
**Стоимость:** бесплатно

Конференция проходит летом в Санкт-Петербурге (кста, в этом году 7 июля, скоро совсем), много докладов по инфобезу различного уровня сложности. Подается в веселой форме, конкурсы, смешной ведущий, демонстрации атак (даже cold-boot как-то делали, с жидким азотом).
Примечательно, что вход свободный, но проводится в будний день.
Есть ещё весенний этап - там соревнование для хакеров))) Окончание этого соревнования и подведение итогов обычно бывает как раз на летней конференции.

Answer (score 0):

http://meetingcpp.ru/

Сам был лишь на C++Russia 2016

Answer (score 0):

раз упомянули NeoQuest, надо упомянуть и [PHDays](http://www.phdays.ru) c [ZeroNights](http://zeronights.ru). ИБ, в Москве.