# Пожалуйста, предложите улучшения в страницу справки про вопросы-соревнования!

Tags: обсуждение

В прошлом мы несколько раз соглашались, что вопросы–соревнования — неотъемлемая часть нашего сообщества. Дело осталось за малым — добавить формальные правила в справочный центр.

[Я создал три заготовки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11193/6):

- [страницу справочного центра](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11194/6);
- [шаблон вопроса–соревнования](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11195/6);
- [вопрос-песочницу для соревнований](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11196/6).

Кроме того, я планирую добавить ссылку на новую страницу справки в «[На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

За основу страниц справки я взял материал с сайта [Code Golf Stack Exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), оттуда же взят шаблон вопроса–соревнования и текст вопроса–песочницы.

#### Пожалуйста, предложите ваши улучшения новой страницы справки и мета–вопросов!

Если вы считаете, что необходимо что–то поменять, пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваше предложение ответом в этом вопросе. Опечатки и небольшие ошибки, пожалуйста, исправьте сразу в основном тексте. Примерно через две недели я добавлю результат нашей совместной работы в справку.

Comment: Очень жаль, что Николай [решил нарушать свои собственные правила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1225740/revisions). Какой смысл было придумывать все эти правила, если на практике они не работают и сам их создатель опустился до их нарушения?

Comment: @andreymal Пожалуйста, отметьте тревогой все сообщения, которые по вашему мнению нарушают правила. Тревоги попадут в специальную очередь для модераторов и они смогут принять правильное решение.

Comment: Я их отмечаю уже целый месяц — модераторы отклоняют все тревоги, выдумывая отмазки разной степени глупости. Учитывая, что за основу решений они всё равно будут брать **ваши** действия — модераторы **не могут** принять правильное решение.

Comment: Очень жаль, что Николай [решил нарушать свои собственные правила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1225740/revisions). Помимо того, что он их нарушает <em>(но он ведь КМ, ему можно, наверное?)</em>, он также при этом старательно уклоняется от ответов на прямые вопросы (мы все регулярно наблюдаем это по всей Мете) и [пытается перенести ответственность за свои действия на модераторов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11197/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%

Comment: @andreymal Андрей, а может хватит? Ну нет на свете никакой демократии, и никогда ее не будет, и пора уже с этим смириться. Если у вас есть цель или мечта создать идеальную базу знаний и идеальное сообщество, то создайте свой личный сайт. И при всем этом и там, на вашем сайте, не будет никакой демократии. Потому что она будет только в ваших глазах. В глазах же некоторых других участников они будут видеть то, что сейчас вы видите здесь. Сколько людей, столько же и мнений. У каждого своя демократия и своя правда жизни. Примите это как должное. Будьте здоровы!

Comment: @Sevastopol' при чём тут демократия? Речь идёт о нарушении правил сайта. Не о демократии и не о идеальных базах — а о нарушении существующих правил.

Comment: @andreymal, вы пишите, что Николай `решил нарушать свои собственные правила`. А какие у вас к нему тогда вопросы или претензии, если это не общие и для всех правила, а его собственные? Хочет - соблюдает, не хочет - нарушает, имеет на это полное право. А вы спрашиваете - причем тут демократия...

Comment: @Sevastopol' претензии к тому, что администрация сайта поощряет нарушение правил вот такими вот действиями. Николай-то не в своём посте что-то написал, а чужой пост отредактировал — тем самым «узаконив» нарушение правил и показав всем пользователям, что нарушать правила если очень хочется, то можно. Никакого нормального человека, имеющего хотя бы базовые представления о справедливости, такая ситуация устраивать не может.

Comment: @andreymal, справедливость (в данном случае) это когда демократия. Но демократии нигде никогда не было, нет и не будет. Это нужно понять и принять. Миллион раз я вам уже писал об этом - ни за то боритесь. Поберегите, Андрей, свои нервные клетки и будьте здоровы!

Comment: @Sevastopol' вы опять уводите тему в демагогию подальше от конкретных фактов нарушения правил. С такой демагогией действительно лучше разговор не продолжать.

Answer (score 6):

То, что сообщество решило легализовать вопросы-соревнования, это хорошо. На мой взгляд есть вероятность, что новые участники будут путать **вопросы-соревнования** и **конкурсы**. Поэтому предлагаю добавить в раздел справки о соревнованиях следующее:

> ## В чем отличие Соревнования от конкурса?
>
> Конкурс — это объявление награды в виде баллов репутации за лучший
> ответ на вопрос. Вы можете объявить конкурс, чтобы привлечь
> дополнительное внимание к вопросу. Длительность конкурса составляет 7
> дней.
>
> Конкурс стоит объявлять, если Вам необходим ответ или решение
> какой-либо прикладной задачи. Конкурс можно объявить только через 48 часов после того, как был задан вопрос. см. раздел [конкурсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) для получения
> более подробной информации.
>
> Соревнования — это события в сообществе, которыми мы вместе привносим
> чуточку веселья в ежедневное участие на сайте, оставаясь в рамках
> правил сайта и сохраняя атмосферу знаний. Например, «Новогодний
> алгоритм». Соревнования, в отличие от конкурса, можно объявлять сразу же, во время создания вопроса, добавив метку «соревнование». Длительность соревнований неограниченна (или дата окончания выбирается автором к определенному празднику или событию).

Еще я бы ввел специальную метку соревнование, чтобы обозначить, нужен ли пользователю серьезный ответ или он пришел повеселиться.

И в качестве идеи: можно сделать так, чтобы соревнования имели "призовой фонд", в который либо скидываются неравнодушные участники либо сам автор соревнования его формирует. Тогда можно будет выбрать 1, 2 и 3 место и начислить соответственно 50%, 35% и 15% репутации призерам от общего призового фонда, тогда будет прям настоящее соревнование.

Comment: Хорошая мысль разделить понятия **соревнование**, как действие по написание одной, самой короткой, самой остроумной или нескольких строчек кода по определенному чёткому заданию и **конкурсу анимаций**, где может быть и несколько сотен строчек кода и требование совершенно другие - получить качественную анимацию по заданному сценарию. Поэтому поддерживаю вашу мысль, чётко разделить в справке эти два термина. И написать два раздела справки: один для соревнований, второй отдельный раздел справки для конкурсов анимаций. метка *соревнование* существует довольно давно и на Мете и на SO

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Я говорил о конкурсах, которые доступны сейчас и существуют для привлечения  к вопросу. Пройдите по ссылке в ответе. Ваша идея о двух разных видах соревнований, это не то что я имел в виду)).

Comment: вот именно по этому пункту справки о конкурсах ломаются копья уже целый год, появление этого топика КМ именно и вызвано этой проблемой, чтобы решить её. По вопросам соревнованиям особых вопросов и не возникало. Просто нельзя объединить очень разные вещи в одной разделе справки. Нужны два отдельных раздела справки. В качестве прототипа  я предлагал [решение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10397/28748)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT отдельную страницу справки и создают. Я просто предложил уточнить это и выделить отдельным разделом. Думаю, еще можно добавить туда, что соревнование изначально создается как соревнование и требует репутацию от автора, а конкурс можно назначить лишь через два дня после того, как задали обычный вопрос, чтобы еще больше подчеркнуть различие между этими понятиями.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH по разному было... И как обычный конкурс провели  по написанию кода под меткой **соревнование** с назначенным вознаграждением +300 [Код-гольф: Обход двумерного массива змейкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/926927/28748) и на Мете конкурс провели [Новогодний алгоритм 2016](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2235/28748) без вознаграждения репой, но с вручением подарков от КМ Поэтому всё так запутано и я считаю, что  пора написать всё четко В общем проект КМ справки, как раз и полностью подходит к соревнованиям, но для конкурсов анимации нужен отдельный раздел справки

Comment: Собственно, [вот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11166/176217) об этом же.

Comment: _"Если вы не уверены, является ли ваш вопрос конкурсом или соревнованием, пожалуйста, задайте вопрос на Мете."_ - что-то мне это не нравится - в каком случае может быть непонятно? А метка [tag:соревнование] уже существует же.

Comment: @Qwertity я пока скопировал то, что было у Николаса и дописал отсебятины. Мне еще не понятно, как в рамках соревнования может быть задано несколько вопросов? Наверное, эти два абзаца надо удалить.

Comment: Спасибо! [Внес измненеия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/11194/revisions) согласно вашим рекомендациям.

Answer (score 3):

Вижу несколько недоработок, над которыми стоит подумать:

1. Соревнования по анимации не вписываются в пункт о наличии входных и выходных данных - надо бы с этим что-то сделать.
2. Вероятно стоит добавить в шаблон раздел с критерием победы. И для некоторых случаев (например, code golf) c таблицей лидеров - если она может обновляться автоматически и при этом не является рейтингом ответов.
3. <s>Насколько правильно использовать адрес `/help/code-golf`, ведь не все соревнования - это гольф.</s>
4. У нас довольно мало вопросов-соревнований - действительно ли нам уже нужна песочница и будет ли в ней достаточно внимания от других участников?

Comment: почему не вписываются? на входе = что надо анимировать, на выходе - как

Comment: _/help/code-golf_ - тут по аналогии с сайтом  Code Golf Stack Exchange - там тоже не только код гольф, но по началу это сбивает ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy, тогда получится, что анимироваться должен произвольный инпут? Или нет? Если на выходе как, то уже сами анимации придумывать нельзя, только реализовывать описанные в вопросе.

Comment: @Grundy, хм.. Про сайт пожалуй согласен - тогда да, пусть будет.

Comment: _тогда получится, что анимироваться должен произвольный инпут?_ - так инпут - это тоже входные данные :) _Если на выходе как, то уже сами анимации придумывать нельзя, только реализовывать описанные в вопросе._ - тут по идее от формулировки может зависеть

Comment: Короче, все те псевдоконкурсы, к которым у меня есть претензии, по новой справке всё равно должны быть закрыты

Comment: @Grundy, в любом случае, тут будет много вопросов. Надо как-то в ту сторону тоже покопать.

Comment: @andreymal, она пока ещё не справка, а только черновик ;)

Comment: @andreymal, до приведения их в соответствие с правилами ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy ну а чё ж уже больше полугода никто не хочет приводить-то ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal, это уже другой вопрос :)

Comment: @andreymal как будут правила - тогда и начнём в порядок приводить

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov существующие прямо сейчас правила никто не отменял

Comment: Согласен по поводу песочницы. Скорее всего, она может не понадобиться вовсе.

Comment: Таблица лидеров — идея хорошая. С другой стороны, поддерживать такую таблицу сложно, а иногда вовсе невозможно.  В тоже время, как я понимаю, можно сделать что–то универсальное, [как в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/849931/6). Буду очень благодарен (и обязательно добавлю в шаблон), если вы предложите скрипт создания таблицы и пояснение, как его использовать.